# Dicionário de Expressão Regular e Deserialização de JSON

Tags: c#, json, regex, serialização

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que recebe JSON de diversos layouts por um canal único e a classe de Roteador deve identificar qual layout se trata por expressão regular e realizar a deserialização para a classe correta.

No protótipo utilizei `if` aninhados, mas gostaria de uma solução mais dinâmica, pensei em utilizar dicionario com chave sendo o Regex e o valor a classe a ser deserializada, mas gostaria de ajuda se essa seria a melhor solução (e como implementar da melhor forma) ou se outra solução seria indicada.

Abaixo o código que comecei a desenvolver:

```
public class Roteador {

    internal static RegexOptions regOpcoes = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled;

    internal static string PatternMsg0002 = "\"Event\"(\\s)*:(\\s)*\"Msg0002\"?";
    internal static string PatternMsg0003 = "\"Event\"(\\s)*:(\\s)*\"Msg0003\"?";
    internal static string PatternMsg0003 = "\"Event\"(\\s)*:(\\s)*\"Msg0004\"?";

    internal static Regex regexMsg0002 = new Regex(PatternMsg0002, regOpcoes);
    internal static Regex regexMsg0003 = new Regex(PatternMsg0003, regOpcoes);
    internal static Regex regexMsg0004 = new Regex(PatternMsg0004, regOpcoes);

    internal static Dictionary<Regex, ClasseBase> dicRegex = new Dictionary<Regex, ClasseBase>();

    public static void IntegrarMensagem(string mensagem)
    {

        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        ClasseBase meuObjeto;

        if (regexMsg0002.IsMatch(mensagem))
            meuObjeto = (ClasseFilha1)serializer.Deserialize(textoJson, typeof(ClasseFilha1));
        else if (regexMsg0003.IsMatch(mensagem))
            meuObjeto = (ClasseFilha2)serializer.Deserialize(textoJson, typeof(ClasseFilha2));
        else if (regexMsg0004.IsMatch(mensagem))
            meuObjeto = (ClasseFilha3)serializer.Deserialize(textoJson, typeof(ClasseFilha3));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, como estou no meio do expediente a solução ficoubastante bagunçada mas espero que entenda:

**Roteador:**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Testes.Models;

public class Roteador
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Regex> DicionarioDePadroes;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<string, ClasseBase>> DicionarioDeDesserializadores;

    public Roteador(string rotas)
    {
        var dicionarioTemporario = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(rotas);
        DicionarioDePadroes = new Dictionary<string, Regex>(dicionarioTemporario.Count);
        dicionarioTemporario.ToList().ForEach(kvp =>
        {
            try
            {
                DicionarioDePadroes.Add(kvp.Key, new Regex(kvp.Value, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled));
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        });
        DicionarioDeDesserializadores = new Dictionary<string, Func<string, ClasseBase>>();
        foreach (var kvp in DicionarioDePadroes)
        {
            var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == kvp.Key);
            if (type != default(Type) && type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ClasseBase)))
                DicionarioDeDesserializadores.Add(kvp.Key, jsonValue => (ClasseBase)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonValue, type));
        }
    }

    public ClasseBase IntegrarMensagem(string mensagem)
    {
        ClasseBase meuObjeto = null;

        var nomeClasse = DicionarioDePadroes.Where(kvp => kvp.Value.IsMatch(mensagem))?.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).FirstOrDefault();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nomeClasse) && DicionarioDeDesserializadores.TryGetValue(nomeClasse, out Func<string, ClasseBase> parser))
            meuObjeto = parser(mensagem);

        return meuObjeto;
    }
}
```

**Classe Base**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
public class ClasseBase
{
    [JsonProperty]
    private string Event { get; set; }
}
```

**Classe 1:**

```
using System;
public class Classe1 : ClasseBase
{
    public int Param1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Param2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Classe 2:**

```
public class Classe2 : ClasseBase
{
    public int Param1 { get; set; }
    public string Param2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Teste do código:**

```
var formatos = "{\"Classe1\": \"\\\"Event\\\"(\\\\s)*:(\\\\s)*\\\"Classe1\\\"?\\\"\", \"Classe2\": \"\\\"Event\\\"(\\\\s)*:(\\\\s)*\\\"Classe2\\\"?\\\"\"}";
var roteador = new Roteador(formatos);
#region Testes de desserialização da Classe1 e Classe2
var jsonValueClasse1 = "{\"Event\":\"Classe1\",\"Param1\":5,\"Param2\":\"2018-05-22T22:00:00.000\"}";
var jsonValueClasse2 = "{\"Event\":\"Classe2\",\"Param1\":5,\"Param2\":\"Testes\"}";

var classe1 = roteador.IntegrarMensagem(jsonValueClasse1);
var classe2 = roteador.IntegrarMensagem(jsonValueClasse2);

#endregion
```